# How to make JTable headers visible in JFrame?

Tags: java, mysql

I wanted to display table records with their respective columns from a MySQL database.

This is what I tried to do:

```
(e.getSource().equals(btnClick)) {

 //Table
 JTable table = new JTable();
 JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
                                            
String[] columnNames = new String[] {"Staff ID", "Name", "Email", "Address", "Phone","Gender"};
                                            
table.setBounds(500,50, 550,300); 

try {
                                                        
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM staffs";

  PreparedStatement pstmt = ConnectDb.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
  ResultSet rslt = pstmt.executeQuery();
                                                                                                                  
                                                        
  table.setModel(net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rslt));  
                                                        
} catch (Exception ex) {
                                                             
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                                                             
 frm.setVisible(true);

}

}

  frm.add(btnClick);
  frm.add(table);
```

As a result, its only the rows data which are shown while the table headers remain hidden.

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: `frm.add(scroll);` not `frm.add(table);`

Comment: The whole table disappears when I do that.

Comment: Shouldn't. But I suspect you're doing something odd with layout (e.g. having a null layout). Can you please edit and post your full gui code?

Comment: Yes I am eventually using a null layout for the JFrame.

Comment: Not good. That might be at the root of the problem

Comment: Yes, true. When I've removed the null layout the table headers actually displayed but now the table is taking the whole JFrame. Do you know how I can modify its width and change its location on the frame?

Comment: You need to use a layout manager. I don't know what you want your gui to look like or what other components are on it. Of course, you don't need to display it in your frame at all, necessarily. You could display it in another `JDialog` or something

Comment: Actually I have some textfields, textarea and buttons on the left side of the frame (which takes my desktop) and I want to position the table at the right side of the frame without affecting the position of my other components since I've set their position manually when I've used the null layout.

Comment: Sketchy, but you could then place a panel of your controls `BorderLayout.WEST` and add the table `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Thanks for using my `DBUtils`.btw: there is a donate button on the page if you're so inclined ;) https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/22-resultset-to-tablemodel